# Returning class's list parameter gives TypeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, typeerror

I want to create a right angled triangle class within my shape class. The triangle takes 1 parameter: a list of 3 coordinate tuples.

Example:

```
__init__(self, vertices):
self.vertices = vertices
```

The following makes an instance:

```
t = RightAngledTriangle([(0, 0), (0, 4), (3, 4)])
```

The class needs to have a function which outputs all the vertices as a list of tuples, but if I try

```
return self.vertices
```

I get

```
'TypeError: 'list' object is not callable'
```

class RightAngledTriangle(Shape):

```
    def __init__(self, vertices):
        self.vertices = vertices
        self.origin = self.vertices[0]
        self.x_points = []
        self.y_points = []
        for i in self.vertices:
            self.x_points.append(i[0])
            self.y_points.append(i[1])

    def area(self):
        return 0.5 * (max(self.x_points) - min(self.x_points)) * (max(self.y_points) - min(self.y_points))

    def vertices(self):
        return self.vertices
```

Expected Output:

```
t.vertices() -> [(0, 0), (0, 4), (3, 4)]
```

Test Result:

```
'list' object is not callable
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the name of the method (`verticies()`) or the variable `self.verticies` - it appears to be trying to call the variable that is not callable.

Comment: I should add that the area() function is working as intended.

Comment: Of course you could just skip the method() and just use `t.verticies` without the parens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class has an attribute `vertices` and a method `vertices()` with the same name. That is not allowed. The method `area()` works because there is no `area` attribute in conflict with it.

Comment: Interesting, changed them all to something else and it works fine. Thanks for the help.